# How to correctly size Windows forms controls?

Tags: c, windows

I want my application to have a dropdown at the top to select the drive. I added a rebar toolbar tot the main window, and added a combobox to the toolbar. The problem is that the dropdown is not visible because the toolbar stays 4 pixels high. It is supposed to take over the height of the contents. How do I make the toolbar (or any other window/control) take over the size of the contents?

I tried MoveWindow but this doesn't seem to do anything. I am willing to use another control that the rebar.

[Here](https://github.com/Sjord/checkmate/blob/master/mp3checker/windows/rebar.c#L181) is the CreateWindow that creates the toolbar which I call from the [WinMain](https://github.com/Sjord/checkmate/blob/master/mp3checker/windows/mp3checker.c#L111). On `WM_SIZE` I call [Rebar_Resize](https://github.com/Sjord/checkmate/blob/master/mp3checker/windows/rebar.c#L149).

It currently looks like this:

[image]

I want something like this, preferably with an additional label before the dropdown:

[image]

Edit: I tried the [Windows SDK rebar sample](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/winui/controls/common/rebar) and it has the same problem. The rebar is also just 4 pixels high and doesn't show its contents.

Answer (score 0):

My code was programmed for an older API of the rebar common control. One way to fix this is to tell Windows which version of the API you want to use.

> Define the correct platform target before including commctrl.h:
>
> ```
> #define WINVER              0x0501
> #define _WIN32_WINNT        0x0501
> #include <commctrl.h>
> ```

Source: [Rebar Control Not Displaying?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/YbGM-TQB-Mo)